# Reading an image from same directory?

Tags: c++, image, file, makefile, header-files

Suppose I have been given an image called `in.png` in the same directory as my `main.cpp`. I have to read that image and put it into `b` i created in the `main` body. I have been given a `class PNG`, and the function to read the image. I have also posted my algorithm below, I last took C programming language 3 years ago, now am in C++ and I have forgotten a lot. Why doesn't my algorithm work, what is wrong

In png.h;

```
class PNG
{
public:
    PNG(string const & file_name);
    /**
    * Copy constructor: creates a new PNG image that is a copy of
    * another.
    * @param other PNG to be copied.
    */
};
```

in png.cpp, we have;

```
PNG::PNG(string const & file_name)
{
    _pixels = NULL;
    _read_file(file_name);
}
```

In main.cpp, this is my code;

```
int main
{
    PNG a;                        
    PNG*b = NULL;
    b = a.PNG(string const & in.png);
    if(*b = NULL)
        cout << "The image wasn't read" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

thanks

EDIT     ------------------------------------------------------

Hello Mr. R Sahu,
So, I want to be able to rotate this image. So, I have created another object called "b", I was hoping that I would get rotated data from "a" and put it in "b". I decided to use a function declared in PNG, but it is declared as a "class" of a pixel, just like PNG is a class of an image. But I am having errors using it, what is wrong with my code. The codes with "//" are things I tried before and didn't work.

The code has multiple files;

in PNG.h, we now have the function defined as;

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rgbapixel.h"
class PNG
{
public:
RGBAPixel * operator()(size_t x, size_t y);
/**
* Const pixel access operator. Const version of the previous
* operator(). Does not allow the image to be changed via the
* pointer.
* @param x X-coordinate for the pixel pointer to be grabbed from.
* @param y Y-cooridnate for the pixel pointer to be grabbed from.
* @return A pointer to the pixel at the given coordinates (can't
*      change the pixel through this pointer).
*/
size_t width() const;   // returns width
size_t width() const;
private:
// storage
size_t _width;
size_t _height;
RGBAPixel * _pixels;
};
```

The functions were implemented for us in png.cpp. So, in main.cpp, I have my code to use them;

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include "rgbapixel.h"
#include "png.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "me..........." << endl;
PNG a("in.png");
PNG b;
for(size_t i = 0; i < a.width(); i++)
{
for(size_t j = 0; j <a.height(); j++)
{
// *b(i, j) = *a(j, i);                               erata
// b(i,j) = RGBAPixel * operator()(size_t x, size_t y);
//  b(i, j) = operator()(i, j);              
//b(i,j) = *operator(i,j);
//b(j,i) = a*operator(i,j);
//b(j,i) = a.operator(i,j);
//b(j, i) = a.*operator(i,j);
}
}
b.writeToFile("output.png");
return 0;
}
```

I am getting errors with using the function, I can't tell what's wrong. So, I don't know whether my alogarithm will get the image rotated

some errors;

```
[jonathan2@linux-a1 lab_intro]$ make
clang++ -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -c -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
main.cpp:24:29: error: expected ')'
b(i,j) = *operator(i,j);
                        ^
main.cpp:24:28: note: to match this '('
b(i,j) = *operator(i,j);
                       ^
main.cpp:24:20: error: use of undeclared 'operator()'
b(i,j) = *operator(i,j);
               ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
int main()
{
    // Construct a PNG object by passing the name
    // of the png file to the constructor.
    PNG a("in.png");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so if I want to write that image to a file which does the opposite of the given function, wuld I do a.write_out("output.png").... would that work?

Comment: @user124627, if the class `PNG` has such a function, then yes, it should.